# Recursive Merge Sort In C++

Tags: c++, sorting, recursion, merge

I'm trying to code a merge sort in c++, but building it gives me a warning that it's recursive, and running it gives a stack overflow. I don't understand where I'm doing wrong.

```
void mergesort(int thelist[]) {
  if (sizeof(thelist) <= 1)
    return;

  int middle = (sizeof(thelist) / 2);
  for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(thelist); i++){
    if (i < middle)
      lft[i] = thelist[i];
    else if (i >= middle)
      rght[i-middle] = thelist[i];
  }
  mergesort(lft);
  mergesort(rght);
  merge(lft, lft + 10, rght, rght + 10, sortedlist);
}
```

Comment: `sizeof()` doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: Why is there a `10` buried in your code. You need to pass the sequence length. `sizeof(theist)` isn't doing what you think it is. Your `mergsesort` declaration should be `void mergesort(int thelist[], size_t len)` and `sizeof` should be *nowhere* in this function. Further, I can only imagine you're using globals for `lft` and `rght`, and I can tell you now it isn't going to do what you think it will.

Comment: You have an ever ending recursive loop as `if (sizeof(thelist) <= 1)
` is always false, since `sizeof(thelist)` is size of a pointer. You need to pass an extra argument - `size_t size` which tells the size of the `thelist` array.

Comment: How are you testing the code? What's the stack trace? Where is merge? The more information you provide, the better able we'll be to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to handle different parts of `int []` by calling the same function, try to define your function as

   ```
   void mergesort(int thelist[], int start, int end)
   ```
2. Regarding the `sizeof(thelist)` part, if you want to get the size of a `int []`. You need to use

   ```
   sizeof(thelist)
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   sizeof(thelist)/sizeof(int)
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   int n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int); // n=5 now
   ```

PS: You also need to think twice on your code logic and rewrite it. You main function should looks like the following:

```
void MergeSort(int data[], int start, int end)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        int middle = (start+end)/2;

        // sort for first part
        MergeSort(data, start, middle);

        // sort for second part
        MergeSort(data, middle+1, end);

        // merge both parts together
        Merge(data, start, middle, end);
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunaly, in the context of the function, `sizeof thelist/sizeof int` won't work. (in C, but I am almost sure in C++ too)

Comment: the example works in C as well, but the problem is that is not clear if you are suggesting the usage in the callee or in the caller; in the callee, it won't work. — and in the caller will work if he has declared the array as you did.

Comment: @ShinTakezou #1 is just to clarify how to right use `sizeof()` to get the size. You are right that he/she cannot just put this in the code, combined with #2 instead.

Comment: So, it's not clear since you suggest to replace `sizeof` with `sizeof/sizeof`, and to me it seems you are suggesting to do it inside the function.

Comment: Thanks, but more information would be great. The 'merge' function apparently takes 5 arguments that don't match with yours, and I think that 'start' and 'end' are supposed to be the first and last items in the array, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @William Yes, I didn't show the final `Merge()` to merge two sorted arrays together here. You should be able to deliver it.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void merge(int *, int *, int, int, int);
void mergesort(int *a, int *b, int low, int high)
{
    int pivot;
    if (low < high)
    {
        pivot = (low + high)/2;
        mergesort(a, b, low, pivot);
        mergesort(a, b, pivot + 1, high);
        merge(a, b, low, pivot, high);
    }
}
void merge(int *a, int *b, int low, int pivot, int high)
{
    int h, i, j, k;
    h = low;
    i = low;
    j = pivot + 1;

    while ((h <= pivot) && (j <= high)) // Traverse both halves of the array
    {
        if (a[h] <= a[j]) // if an element of left half is less than element of right half
        {
            b[i] = a[h]; // store element of left half in the temporary array
            h++; // shift the index of the array from which the element was copied to temporary 
        }
        else // otherwise store the element of the right half in the temporary array
        {
            b[i] = a[j];
            j++; // shift the index of the array from which the element was copied to temporary 
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (h > pivot) // If traversal of left half is done, 
                   // copy remaining elements from right half to temporary
    {
        for (k = j; k <= high; k++)
        {
            b[i] = a[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    else // otherwise copy remaining elements from left half to temporary
    {
        for (k = h; k <= pivot; k++)
        {
            b[i] = a[k];
            i++;
        }
    }
    for (k = low; k <= high; k++) a[k] = b[k]; // recopy the values from temporary to original array.
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {12, 10, 43, 23, -78, 45, 123, 56, 98, 41, 90, 24};
    int num;

    num = sizeof(a)/sizeof(int);

    int b[num]; // temporary array to be used for merging

    mergesort(a, b, 0, num-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You should add some text explaining what your code's about and why this answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void print_arr_data(std::vector<int>& arr, int start, int end) {
    cout << "start: " << start << " end: " << end << endl;
    int len = abs(end - start) + 1;
    for(auto it = arr.begin() + start; it != arr.begin() + start + len; ++it) {
        cout << *it << ",";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void merge(std::vector<int>& arr, int start, int end) {
    int len = abs(start - end);
    std::sort(arr.begin() + start, arr.begin() + start + len);
}

void merge_sort(std::vector<int>& arr, int start, int end) {
    // check if the array is not a unit array, then dont divide anymore
    print_arr_data(arr, start, end);

    if (start < end) {
        int mid = (start + end)/2;

        merge_sort(arr, start, mid);
        merge_sort(arr, mid+1, end);
        merge(arr, start, end);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data = {4,1,2,3,7,8,5,6,9};
    merge_sort(data, 0, data.size()-1);

    cout << "*******" << endl;
    for (int i : data) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    cout << "*******";

    return 0;
}
```